# Seroconversion rate in R

Tags: r, plot

I need your help in sero-conversion rate plot. I use the code:

```
proportions <- plot_data %>%
  group_by(Age) %>%
  summarize( 
    Prop_pfmsp119 = sum(Sero_pfmsp119 == 1, na.rm = TRUE) / n(),
    Prop_pfama1 = sum(Sero_pfama1== 1, na.rm = TRUE) / n(),
    Prop_pvama1 = sum(Sero_pvama1== 1, na.rm = TRUE) / n(),
    prop_pvmsp119=sum(sero_pvmsp119== 1, na.rm = TRUE)/n()
  )
proportions <- proportions[proportions$Prop_pfmsp119 > 0, ]
proportions <- proportions[proportions$Prop_pfama1 > 0, ]
proportions <- proportions[proportions$Prop_pvama1 > 0, ]
proportions=proportions[proportions$prop_pvmsp119 > 0, ]
;then the plot is:
p1 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Age, y = p)) +
  geom_point(data=proportions,aes(x = Age , y = Prop_pfama1),col="red") +
  # geom_smooth(method="glm",se=T,color="black",method.args = list(family=binomial))+
  #geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = TRUE, color = "black", linewidth = 1) +
  labs(x = "Age (in years)", y = "Probability of Positive") +
  ggtitle("PfAMA1") +
  geom_text(x = 45, y = 0.9, label = "λ = 0.010;95% CI:(0.006-0.014)", color = "black", size = 4) +
  theme_classic() +
  #scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 20)) +
  ylim(0,1)+
  #geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = l_p, ymax = u_p), fill = "red", linetype = "dashed")
  
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(aes(y=u_p),linetype="dashed")+
  geom_line(aes(y=l_p),linetype="dashed")+
  theme_classic()
```

But the point is out of the CI:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a problem with (prob-age) points outside computed CIs. Do you want to colour-code them (e.g. inside blue, outside red)? What is the benefit of it? In my opinion, it adds nothing than confusion.

Comment: The CI is for the mean ( or perhaps some other central estimate). It would be expected to see many points on either side of the estimated mean.

Comment: Btw. This is still in the wrong forum. It should have been addressed to https://stats.stackexchange.com .  It’s not a question about how to program but rather about how to interpret output.